# Where to find Bugs fixed in Point Releases or Addressed to be fixed in Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, updates, release-management

Since according to this [Release Schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseSchedule?action=show&redirect=PreciseReleaseSchedule) the 12.04.1 point release is expected on 23 August 2012.

As per the [Point release wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PointReleaseProcess) in `Release minus 1 month` that `all candidate bugs are fixed` .

Where to find the list of Bugs that will be targeted to be fixed or fixed . Or changelogs as [here](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/) *( not up-to-date i guess for PR)*

**P.S.**: I guess it is too early to ask this question , if it is comment so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the **Ubuntu-12.04.1 Launchpad page** for Upcoming Point release 12.04.1 here

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+milestone/ubuntu-12.04.1

It mentions all the Bugs that are being addressed and are in Progress to get fix.

[image]